# Using lodash to prepare data for "last day user registration" chart

Tags: angularjs, lodash, chart.js

I want to use lodash to prepare data for "last day user registration" chart.

Here is my users array:

```
{
  name: toto,
  creationDate: 11/11/2016 11:00:00
},
{
  name: tata,
  creationDate: 11/11/2016 10:00:00
},
{
  name: titi,
  creationDate: 09/11/2016 10:00:00
}
```

I need to create a chart with ChartJS that repesent the users registrations over th last day (24 hours).

If I use groupBy :

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(users, function (user) {
      return moment(user.creationDate).get('hour');
    });
```

I can't have the "empty" hours, when there is no user registration, in the final array.

The aim is to have this (let's say it is 18h o'clock) :

```
labels = ['18', '17', '16', ... '18']
data = [['1', '1', '12, ... '3']]
```

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a defauls object with empty arrays and apply `_.defaults`:

```
var hours = _.range(0,24);
var defaultHours = _.zipObject(hours, _.map(hours, function(){return [];}));

_.defaults(grouped, defaultHours);
```

After that, `grouped` will hold the values you found, or empty array for hours that had no registrations.

Comment: Will it take the fact that it must only count the "last 24 hours" ? I mean if a registration is done two days before at 15h, is this 15 counted with the 15 of today ?

Comment: It won't, since your original code didn't. You will first need to filter out entries that are more than 24 hours old. 
var recentUsers = _.filter(users, function(user){
return moment(user.creationDate).diff(Date.now(), 'hours', true) < 24;
}   
and then do your groupBy operation on recentUsers